# adding request id in request using MDC in zuul gateway service doesn't reflect client micro service application

Tags: java, spring-boot, filter, netflix-zuul, gateway

I have written a Pre filter in zuul gateway

```
@Override
    public Object run() throws ZuulException
    {
        String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        MDC.put("request_id", uniqueID);
        RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = requestContext.getRequest();
        request.setAttribute("request_id", uniqueID);

        //requestContext.set("request_id", uniqueID);
        logger.info("request-id generated is => {}", uniqueID);
        logger.info("Pre Filter => "+ String.format("%s request to %s", request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURL().toString()));
//        MDC.clear();
        return null;
    }
```

Zuul gateway logs -> request Id added and appended in logs

```
2022-08-22 01:57:00.283+0200 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] INFO  [] c.h.z.ZuulGatewayApplication$MyFilter - BEFORE
2022-08-22 01:57:00.284+0200 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] INFO  [f40d9b07-c33f-4996-bb3a-b16df3ba6436] c.h.z.filter.MDCLoggingPreFilter - request-id generated is => f90447a5-974d-4c38-beba-377addce446c
2022-08-22 01:57:00.284+0200 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] INFO  [f40d9b07-c33f-4996-bb3a-b16df3ba6436] c.h.z.filter.MDCLoggingPreFilter - Pre Filter => GET request to http://localhost:8080/home
2022-08-22 01:57:00.285+0200 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] INFO  [f40d9b07-c33f-4996-bb3a-b16df3ba6436] c.h.z.f.MDCLoggingPreFilter2 - Pre Filter 2 => GET request to http://localhost:8080/home
2022-08-22 01:57:00.297+0200 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] INFO  [f40d9b07-c33f-4996-bb3a-b16df3ba6436] c.h.z.f.MDCLoggingPostFilter - Post Filter => GET request to http://localhost:8080/home
2022-08-22 01:57:00.298+0200 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] INFO  [f40d9b07-c33f-4996-bb3a-b16df3ba6436] c.h.z.f.MDCLoggingPostFilter2 - Post Filter 2=> GET request to http://localhost:8080/home
2022-08-22 01:57:00.299+0200 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] INFO  [f40d9b07-c33f-4996-bb3a-b16df3ba6436] c.h.z.ZuulGatewayApplication$MyFilter - AFTER
```

Screenshot
[image]

but when the request forwards to client application , there is no request Id

```
2022-08-22 01:57:00.287+0200 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] INFO  [] c.h.z.controller.HomeController - simple get method
```

Screen Shot For Client microservice
[image]